# Deep-Link Error with Flutter and Supabase. Unhandled Exception: AuthException(message: No access_token detected., statusCode: null)

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, mobile, supabase

I have a working small Project which uses a supabase-backend for Data and Authentication. Everything works as intended and especially the OAuth works like a charm.

Now i wanted to implement Deep-Links for my custom Business Logic (before only Supabase was using deep links for OAuth). And i get it to work (I can receive links when i open it via a Scheme).

BUT it also throws an error, because of Supabase. Whenever i open the App via a link, i get the Error:

```dart
I/flutter (21576): ***** SupabaseDeepLinkingMixin startAuthObserver <-- Supabase handler
I/flutter (21576): ***** SupabaseAuthState handleDeeplink http://mydomain/tempdev
I/flutter (21576): onReceivedAuthDeeplink uri: http://mydomain/tempdev
E/flutter (21576): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: AuthException(message: No access_token detected., statusCode: null)
E/flutter (21576):
E/flutter (21576): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: AuthException(message: No access_token detected., statusCode: null)
E/flutter (21576):
I/flutter (21576): No access_token detected.
I/flutter (21576): Initial Uri handle <-- My custom handler
```

Ive tried using another scheme for OAuth or Custom stuff and it didnt change anything.

My intent-filters:

```xml
<intent-filter>        
 <action
   android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 <category
   android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <category
   android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 <data
   android:scheme="de.my.package" />   
</intent-filter>
                
<intent-filter>
 <action
   android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 <category
   android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <category
   android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 <data android:scheme="http" android:host="my.hos" />
 <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

I know what the error means: It tries to detect the auth-token when the OAuth-Provider is redirecting to the callback, but fails. But this feels like a weird error, am i doing something wrong? It feels like supabase is checking for an error where there is none, instead of Throwing an error it should just not do anything (?). Can someone explain it to me.

About my Project:

In my Code for handling custom Deep-Links im following the [uni-links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links/example) example.
And for Supabase im using the supabase-flutter package and not doing anything "fancy".

I focus on Deploying it on Android and not doing anything with iOS/Windows/Web.

Is there anything i can do to resolve this? Is this even a "bad" error, or something i can ignore in release-mode? Right now it throws and interrupts while im in debug-mode.

Comment: Did you add the [redirect URLs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth#redirect-urls-and-wildcards) in the [URL configuration](https://app.supabase.com/project/_/auth/url-configuration)?

Comment: @Mansueli I have specified one of the schemes as a redirect URL (And this works). But i never specified the URL im using for custom Deep-Linking (because i dont want supabase to do anything with that)... Supabase is just searching for Auth-Tokens in any deep link and throwing error if it doesnt find any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating a Issue on the flutter_supabase GitHub they showed me that upgrading to supabase_flutter v1.2.1 fixes the error.